# Change the lineend for shapes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot an enlarged plus symbol (+) in ggplot, but make the ends of the lines square, not round.

As you can see in the plot below, the ends of the crosses are rounded, but I want them to be flat (like the ones cut-off at the edge of the plot).

I have tried including a `lineend` argument (like the one used in `geom_segment`) but that just gives a warning and doesn't change the shape.

Does anyone know if this is possible/how to do it?

**Example:**

```
df <- head(iris, 10)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point(shape = 3, size = 5, stroke = 5) +
  theme_bw()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
    geom_point(shape = '+', size = 30, stroke = 5)`

Comment: wow, do you know why the shape + and the shape no. 3 are different? they should be the same I would have thought

Comment: See `?points`; that plotting character happens to look like a typable character, but most of the rest don't, which is why they're referred to by number. Passing an explicit `"+"` uses the text glyph as the plotting character instead of the built-in plotting characters.